# How to sort an array of objects based on scores - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects that contain the data I want to sort (it has more properties), like so:

```
[
    {
        "data": {
            "id": "green"
        }
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "id": "red"
        }
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "id": "blue"
        }
    }
]
```

`id` is a nested property I need to use in order to sort based on scores provided from a different object like so:

```
{
    "green": 5,
    "red": 3,
    "blue": 8
}
```

I'm trying to find the best way to sort my array of object, however no success so far.

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: store the scores object in a variable and `data.sort((a,b) => scores[a.data.id]-scores[b.data.id]);` for descending where data is the array u need to sort. switch a and b  for ascending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort them like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/Ldvja31t/1/

```
const scores = {
    "green": 5,
    "red": 3,
    "blue": 8
};

const myData = [
    {
        "data": {
            "id": "green"
        }
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "id": "red"
        }
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "id": "blue"
        }
    }
];

myData.sort((d1, d2) => {
    return scores[d1.data.id] - scores[d2.data.id]
});

console.log(myData)
```

Answer (score 2):

Javascripts built-in sort function has a optional comparison function parameter.
The following code utilizes this function to solve your problem:

```js
var array = [
    {
        "data": {
            "id": "green"
        }
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "id": "red"
        }
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "id": "blue"
        }
    }
];

var scores =
{
    "green": 5,
    "red": 3,
    "blue": 8
};

array.sort((a, b) => (scores[a.data.id] - scores[b.data.id]));

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

The two answers that were given should work fine. However I would also like to add you could use an Enum. Example

Heres a separate example of an enum usage and sorting it in an array of objects

```
const enum Order {
    Start = 'Start',
    Run = 'Run',
    End = 'End',
}

const predicate = (a, b) => {
    const map = {};
    map[Order.Start] = 1;
    map[Order.Run] = 2;
    map[Order.End] = 3;

    if (map[a] < map[b]) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (map[a] > map[b]) {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

const data = [Order.End, Order.Run, Order.Start];

const result = data.sort(predicate);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: OP is not using Typescript, there are no enums.